# Convert Magento template to simple HTML version

Tags: html, magento, templates

My client has bought a template from Template Monster thinking it was a HTML template. He gave the template to me to make some changes and I noticed it is actually a Magento template. He has no understanding about templates or Magento.

We checked with TM to see if they have a HTML version of it. They don't have one but offered to get a quote to convert it to HTML. My client is not willing to spend more because he has already spent around USD 180 to buy it from them. So he wants me to see if I can convert it to HTML.

I'm also not familiar with Magento or Magento templates. Unfortunately I could only find information about converting from HTML to Magento, not the other way. I checked inside the folders to see if I can find any stylesheets, header, footer etc. But I couldn't find any.

Here is the folder structure of the template:

http://pastebin.com/RhnfZMyL

What would be the easiest way to convert the template to HTML without converting it from the beginning using the PSD file?

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry to say that it would be very difficult to convert it if you don't know anything about magento.Magento uses fallback principle so if didn't find header in your theme than if will search in its base theme. This is quite confusing at first.

If you really want to convert it than i think at first you should install your theme in magento and than analyze it, view the page source to convert it to HTML.But it will not be easy. You can use **template Path Hint** feature of magento to know the file location.

Hope this will help and you will figure out some way.

Regards,

Navin

Answer (score 1):

What is possible to get your client (temporarily) lucky:

You could open and instance of Magento with dummy-data, install the template and grab the whole thing using a scraper.

Then you have a propably very wrong and horrible template together.

I think it is really better to start off with a fresh framework such as Bootstrap or Foundation to get your a nice, clean and neat layout.

May I ask on what system you want to go with the template?

Comment: stylesheets you'll find in the /skin folder.

Comment: html is generated by magento, so you won't be lucky as long as you don't have one to process this through.

Comment: What you mean by "on what system?". My client already has a website. He wants to remove the shopping cart sections from the template and use it in his static website because he likes the template. He doesn't have a shopping cart.

Comment: I thought of scraping the page..But again, it's not a good way.Are u saying the only option is to go with covert from the PSD from beginning?

Comment: waht kind of CMS/Shopsoftware are you goimg to use? You should either buy / make templates specific for that. There is not really another way. 

I'd use PSD templates of the designer as a draft, then CODE the template fitting for the desired CMS/Shop (System) you wanna go to.